# Kubuntu has serif font in some dialogs

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, 15.04

I was going through some settings of my Kubuntu 15.04 installation when I hit 'Defaults' in System Settings > Fonts. I believe this is what caused some texts to display in serif fonts, the best examples are the tab titles in Google Chrome and the texts in dialogs such as for opening files. While this did not break anything, it does look ugly.

EDIT: I've noticed that also browser drop-down menus have disappeared, I suspect it is due to the same incorrect setting.

My Fonts in System Settins read Oxygen-Sans for all but fixed width fonts, which is set to Oxygen Mono. These are sans serif fonts. Also my kdeglobals file reads:

```
...
[General]
BrowserApplication=google-chrome.desktop
ColorScheme=Breeze
Name=Breeze
font=Oxygen-Sans,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
menuFont=Oxygen-Sans,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
shadeSortColumn=true
smallestReadableFont=Oxygen-Sans,8,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
toolBarFont=Oxygen-Sans,9,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
widgetStyle=breeze
...
```

Does anyone know where I can change this font used in the examples above back to its default? Could this be caused by something different than the settings I've been looking at?

I'm not sure if this is important, but I did add the Kubuntu backports ppa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the misplaced setting. I'll put it here in case someone somehow has the same issue.

The setting that had changed and caused some texts in applications, especially the 'open file' and 'save file' dialogues to change, sits in System Settings > Application Style > GNOME Application Style (GTK) > GTK Themes > Font. This suggests that the applications having troubles are GTK applications.

Anyway, putting the Font back to Oxygen-Sans 10 restored the normal look and feel of the applications.